# Array to Range Validation list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a series of validation lists as follow :

```
Sub CreateValidationList()
Dim myrange as range
Dim c as range
Dim Validationlist as string
Set myrange = range("A1:A10")
Validationlist = ""

For each c in myrange
If c.row = 1 Then
    Validationlist = c.row
Else
    Validationlist = Validationlist & ", " & c.row
End If
    With c
        .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Validationlist
        .Value = c.row
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

In reality, my validation list is much more complicated and my range is much bigger (>500 rows). So it takes way longer than I wish it would.

Is there a way to create Validation Lists in batch a bit like we would do when passing an array to a range :

```
Sub ArrayToRange()
Dim myarray as variant
Dim myrange as range
Set myrange = range("A1:A10")
Set myarray = myrange

'Do stuff in array

Range("A1:A10") = myarray
End Sub
```

Hoping it is clear.

Thanks!

Comment: So each cell gets a different list?

Comment: Your code creates different lists for each cell; and the lists consist of the row number up to that row.  Is that a good example for your "more complicated" list?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes each cell gets a different list.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, In my example I kept it simple so it's easier to focus on the actual question. I think the way the lists are generated for each cells is not relevant for the question. If it is I can elaborate

Comment: I don't know how to add multiple, different validation lists to a range in a single step. I think you have to do that part one at a time. So I think the only way to speed up your process would be to speed up your process of creating the lists. You might want to use a microtimer to test and see if that would be of any value. It may not be.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you for your answer. I will look into it as there is probably some room to improve the way my lists are generated. Wishing you a great day

Comment: So I actually found some kind of a solution. I had an other issue where excel would give me an error when opening my workbook and would delete all the data validation. So now I'm using the selection change event to create the validation list only for one cell when it is selected. And using BeforeSave event to delete all the validation lists. It's not pretty but it seems to be working ok.

Comment: @remyfra If it works, who cares if it's pretty!

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes! And most importantly, it is WAY faster as this part is now out of the main code and only creating the needed list when needed